# Is there any way to get feedback from my review decisions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I just want to learn from my past mistakes first of all in triage queue. How can I see all posts that I have reviewed with the final result?

[Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302372/is-there-any-way-to-find-my-previously-failed-review-tests) is a similar post

Comment: You can look at your [review/history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history) page and if you hate clicking a lot, consider my userscript: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100